# Discrete-time Markov Chain; $n$-step transitions

Tags: markov-process

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq0}$ be a discrete-time Markow chain on the state space $S=\{1,2,3\}$ with transition matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
  1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
  0 & 2/3 & 1/3  \\
 2/3 & 1/3 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}

The initial distribution is $\mathbb{P}(X_{0}=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_{0}=2)=\mathbb{P}(X_{0}=3)=1/3$. What is $\mathbb{P}(X_{3} \in \{2,3\})$?

My answer:

First of all we note that $\mathbb{P}(X_{3} \in \{2,3\})=\mathbb{P}(X_{3} = 3)+\mathbb{P}(X_{3} = 2)$. We know that for $n$-step transition probabilities the unconditional form (given the initial distibution) has:

$\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=j)=\displaystyle\sum_{k \in S} \lambda_{k}(P^{n})_{kj}$,

where $\mathbb{P}(X_{0}=i)=\lambda_{i}$.

Using the above we get:

$\mathbb{P}(X_{3}=2)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{3}\lambda_{k}(P^{3})_{k2}=\lambda_{1}P_{12}^{3}+\lambda_{2}P_{22}^{3}+\lambda_{3}P_{32}^{3}=1/3(13/27+14/27+13/27)=40/81$

Similarly:

$\mathbb{P}(X_{3}=3)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{3}\lambda_{k}(P^{3})_{k3}=\lambda_{1}P_{13}^{3}+\lambda_{2}P_{23}^{3}+\lambda_{3}P_{33}^{3}=1/3(7/27+7/27+6/27)=20/81$.

Thus $\mathbb{P}(X_{3} \in \{2,3\})=40/81+20/81=60/81$

For completeness 
$\mathbb{P}(X_{3}=1)=21/81$, as expected. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  $\left(\frac13\quad \frac13\quad \frac13\right) M^3 = \left(\frac{21}{81}\quad \frac{40}{81}\quad \frac{20}{81}\right)$

Comment: @Henry, post as answer?

Comment: Even$$(1/3,1/3,1/3)M^3(0,1,1)^\text{T}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

Yes. $\left(\frac13\quad \frac13\quad \frac13\right) M^3 = \left(\frac{21}{81}\quad \frac{40}{81}\quad \frac{20}{81}\right)$

or as Xi'an says, even  $\left(\frac13\quad \frac13\quad \frac13\right) M^3 \left( \begin{matrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
           1
         \end{matrix}\right) = \dfrac{60}{81}$